# run 64 bit version on 32 bit operating chip

Tags: system, installed-programs

Does anyone in the Ubuntu community know of a way to run the 64 bit version of Ubuntu on a 32 bit operating chip. My old laptop is running an Intel M 1.7, 32 bit chip? 
By way, I mean as a package that I can download and install, rather than trying to type or copy and past many lines of code.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/emulating-64-bit-os-on-32-bit-os says "yes, maybe, but maybe not".

Answer (score 0):

**Nothing is impossible.**

---

*That said, there is no reasonable argument to support wanting to run a 64-bit OS on a 32-bit processor.*

The emulation overheads alone will fully negate any possible / theoretical advantage over just running **14.04 LTS** (32-bit).

Comment: Chrome is stopping support of 32 bit.as it goes, others follow. I have several 32 bit, good working on Ubuntu machines. Just trying to get ahead of the changes, and save a couple of bucks.

Comment: But you could pick up a Celeron **N2830** based laptop (second hand) for under $150.00 .. and that would run Ubuntu **64-bit** fine.